# MobaXterm windows PATH variable prepends system32 directory

Tags: terminal, path, console, environment-variables

So launching CMD in MobaXterm you have the option to user Windows Path variable. However, rather than using the same %PATH%, MobaXterm **prepends** the following directories into %PATH%.

```
C:\Users\${USER_ID}\AppData\Local\Temp\Mxt82\bin;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;
```

I wonder why it does this? This gives us inconsistent behavior as if we launched cmd directly.

Comment: I'm finding this too, and I want to know how to make it stop doing that. It's breaking some things for me.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? The only thing I could find is to start `cmd.exe` from mobaXterm.